# Order table with case in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, case

how can i order table by:

1. First show meets for this day with order meet_time ASC
2. After show meets for next days with order meet_date ASC
3. After show meets for past days with order meet_date DESC

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `meet_date`="2021-08-06" AND `meet_time`>="12:14" THEN 1 WHEN `meet_date`>"2021-08-06" THEN 2 WHEN `meet_date`="2021-08-06" AND `meet_time`<"12:14" THEN 3 WHEN `meet_date`<"2021-08-06" THEN 3 END ASC, `meet_date` ASC,`meet_time` ASC
```

I try with this query but i have problem with order last group (past meets) DESC.

```
meet_id meet_date meet_time meet_type
40  06.08.2021  15:09   pozyskanie mieszkania
38  06.08.2021  17:09   pozyskanie mieszkania
969 17.08.2021  00:59   pozyskanie-mieszkania
967 19.08.2021  12:00   prezentacja
44  17.09.2021  12:09   pozyskanie mieszkania
42  18.09.2021  12:09   pozyskanie mieszkania
39  19.09.2021  12:09   pozyskanie mieszkania
848 25.01.2005  10:05   pozyskanie-mieszkania
656 30.07.2020  05:30   prezentacja
655 30.07.2020  15:30   pozyskanie-mieszkania
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN meet_date = CURRENT_DATE 
              THEN 1
              WHEN TIMESTAMP(meet_date, meet_time) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
              THEN 2
              ELSE 3 END,
         CASE WHEN meet_date <= CURRENT_DATE 
              THEN TIMESTAMP(meet_date, meet_time) + 0
              ELSE DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, meet_date) END
```

Expression 1 sorts by categories (today, after, before).

Expression 2 provides separate sorting within categories.